# Generating an array of time objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I currently have an array of time values as below:

```
//     '6:00pm',
//     '7:00pm',
//     '8:00pm',
//     '9:00pm',
//     '10:00pm',
//     '11:00pm',
//     '12:00am',
//     '1:00am',
//     '2:00am',
//     '3:00am',
//     '4:00am',
//     '5:00am',
//     '6:00am',
//     '7:00am',
//     '8:00am',
//     '9:00am',
//     '10:00am',
//     '11:00am',
//     '12:00pm',
//     '1:00pm',
//     '2:00pm',
//     '3:00pm',
//     '4:00pm',
//     '5:00pm',
```

I'd like to generate an array of objects matching these times in a format like below:

```
[
    {
      time: "6:00",
      Meridiem: "pm"
   },
   {
      time: "7:00",
      Meridiem: "pm"
   }
]
```

But I am stuck halfway to stop at 12 and resume again to 12 and then to 5pm.

I tried something like this,

```
const array = new Array(12);
let timeArray = [];
for(var i=1;i<=array.length;i++){
    let x = {
        time: i,
        meridium: "AM"
    }
    timeArray.push(x);
  };

  console.log(timeArray, 'timeArray')
```

I know it's not correct. Can please someone guide me on the right path?

Comment: That looks reasonable, you just need to start at the right `i` and concatenate a `time` string properly

Comment: Check the regex part of javascript and furthermore to convert into object check JSON.parse method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to programmatically generate the array. You can use the [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) constructor, [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) it, then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the indices to their time. Computing the time involves `i % 12` with a branch to handle changing `0` to `12`.

Since you want a 24-hour period starting at 6 PM, you can create a 24-hour array, then partition it at 6 PM (index 18) and glue it back together using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (among other methods, depending on your use case).

```js
let times = Array(24).fill().map((_, i) => ({
  time: `${i % 12 || 12}:00`,
  Meridiem: i < 12 ? "am" : "pm"
}));

times = [...times.slice(18), ...times.slice(0, 18)];

console.log(times);
```

Comment: Thanks man, but I would like to get rid off that lengthy times array as well and also when it is 12 i should switch to AM.. Is that possible?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Can you edit your question to show complete output for your example input and explain what you need? By "get rid of that length times array" you mean you want to programmatically generate the time?

Comment: Thanks man, what I meant is on your result it starts from 12am, on my question I want the result to start from 6 pm (basically exact same order as my array in my question)...

Comment: OK, I think I understand. How does it look now?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Array.map` to transform each item in your array.

```js
var arr = ['1:00pm',
    '2:00pm',
    '3:00pm',
    '4:00pm',
    '5:00pm',];
var arr1 = arr.map(i=>{
  return {
    time: i.substring(0, i.length - 2),
    meridium : i.substring(i.length - 2),
  }
})

console.log(arr1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use slice method or substring

```
const ArrOfTimeValues = ['6:00pm','7:00pm','8:00pm','9:00pm'];

const DesireFormateArr = [];
const ArrLength = ArrOfTimeValues.length;
for(let i = 0;i<ArrLength;i++){
  let ItemLength = ArrOfTimeValues[i].length;
  let Meridiem = ArrOfTimeValues[i].slice(-2,ItemLength);
  let TimePoints = ArrOfTimeValues[i].slice(0,ItemLength-2);
  let NewItem = {
    time:TimePoints,
    Meridiem:Meridiem
  }
  DesireFormateArr.push(NewItem);
}
console.log(DesireFormateArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` function for time array and `slice` method something like below snippet.

```js
const listOfTime = ['6:00pm','7:00pm','8:00pm','9:00pm','10:00pm','11:00pm','12:00am','1:00am','2:00am','3:00am','4:00am','5:00am','6:00am','7:00am','8:00am','9:00am','10:00am','11:00am','12:00pm','1:00pm','2:00pm','3:00pm','4:00pm','5:00pm'];

var desireFormate = listOfTime.map(function(val,index) {
  return {time: val.slice(-2,listOfTime[index].length), meridium: val.slice(0,listOfTime[index].length-2)};
})

console.log(desireFormate);
```